# SVN + Get Lock error

Tags: svn, visualsvn

SVN => Get Lock is throwing following error:

```
Command Lock
Error   Invalid authz configuration
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a problem with conf/authz file in the Subversion repository on the server.

Comment: what should be there in authz file.  any examples please

Comment: See section 1.3 in:
http://wiki.wsmoak.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Subversion/Configuration